# AngularJS service unit test fails on toEqual

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following Jasmine unit test:

```
describe('getAlertsByUserId', function () {
    it('should get alerts from api/Alert/bob when the username is bob', inject(function (AlertService, $httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'api/Alert/bob').respond(mockAlerts);
        var alerts = AlertService.getAlertsByUserId('bob');
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(alerts).toEqual(mockAlerts);
    }));
});
```

mockAlerts is defined as follows:

```
[{
        date: new Date(2013, 5, 25),
        description: '',
        alertType: 'type1',
        productDescription: 'product',
        pack: 12,
        size: 16,
        unitOfMeasure: 'OZ',
        category: 'cat1',
        stage: 'C',
        status: 'I'
}]
```

When I execute the test in Karma, I get "Expected [ {date:...etc }] to equal [ {date:...etc }]. I have verified the two objects are the same (property/value). I tried removing the Date object, but to no avail. Anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toEqual` will be checking for reference equality, that is the alerts object is THE SAME object as mockAlerts. What you want to check for is object equality. There are a few ways of doing this.

First you could convert your objects to json

```
expect(JSON.stringify(alerts)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockAlerts));
```

That will probably work most of the time, but it does depend on the serializer treating the objects exactly the same way.

Another way you could do it is to use angular.equals.

```
expect(angular.equals(alerts, mockAlerts)).toBeTruthy();
```

Which probably doesn't read as well but should work nicely.